# RFC2560 vs RFC5019

Tags: certificate, pki, rfc, ocsp

I read some documents about [RFC2560](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2560.txt) and [RFC5019](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5019.txt). I realized that both of them are for OCSP to check validity of a certificate but i could not find any differences between them.

Comment: i don't understand your question.can you provide more information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[RFC6960](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6960) (which replaces RFC2560) is a general standard for OCSP protocol implementation. [RFC5019](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5019) is developed by Microsoft to facilitate large environment needs to reduce network overload by adding restrictions/constraints while keeping it still reliable. RFC5019 is still based on RFC2560/6960, just with restrictions. A quote from RFC5019:

> As the use of PKI continues to grow and move into diverse
> environments, so does the need for a scalable and cost-effective
> certificate status mechanism.  Although OCSP as currently defined and
> deployed meets the need of small to medium-sized PKIs that operate on
> powerful systems on wired networks, there is a limit as to how these
> OCSP deployments scale from both an efficiency and cost perspective.
> Mobile environments, where network bandwidth may be at a premium and
> client-side devices are constrained from a processing point of view,
> require the careful use of OCSP to minimize bandwidth usage and
> client-side processing complexity.

That is: RFC6960 is more appropirate for "high cost, low volume" environments and RFC5019 (and Microsoft implementation) supports only "low cost, high volume" environments.